# Get the list of allowed hosts in host-based authentication

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I am aware that I have to add the IP addresses of remote hosts in **pg_hba.conf** file and restart the PostgreSQL server for changes to take effect.

But I would like to get a list of hosts currently allowed for the host-based authentication, directly from the server that is already running.

Similar to how I can get the *max_connections* setting using `show max_connections;`, I would hypothetically imagine it to be something like `show hosts;` or `select pg_hosts();` (*neither really exists*).

Is this possible?

**EDIT:** I understand exposing the hosts would present a security risk. But how about the `psql` utility invoked directly in the database server's terminal? Does it have a special command to get the list?

Comment: I do not think there is a command like that, possibly because it could be considered a security risk to make that kind of info available. I'll see if I can somehow find it though :)

Comment: Note that you can at least see the location of the hba file with `SHOW hba_file;`

Comment: Can't find anytning that will help you except the file location.

Comment: How about using `psql` utility? (Please see edit)

Comment: As far as I know the `psql` utility just executes normal queries. Some of them look like magic but they're all regular queries (except for the commands run on the local filesystem, but those are not related to the remote server).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The psql command at the terminal has no permission to get the list.  Only the PostgreSQL database does.

The best way to do this (if you really must) is to create a PL/PerlU function which reads the pg_hba.conf and parses it, and returns the information in the way you want it.  You could even build a management system for the pg_hba.conf with such functions (reloading the db might get interesting but you could do this with a LISTEN/NOTIFY approach).

Note, however, if you do this, your functions have a security footprint.  You would probably want to just revoke permission to run the functions from public, grant access to nobody, and thus require users be superusers in order to run the functions.  I would personally avoid exposing such critical information to the db unless there was a compelling reason but I could imagine that there could be cases where it might be helpful on balance.  It is certainly dangerous territory however.